# Application.Current.Exit in Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't terminate app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, exit

How should I "properly" programmatically terminate a Windows Phone 8.1 app?
`Application.Current.Exit ();` doesn't work. My code continues right through it.
Here's the snippet:

```
    public static async Task ShowAndGo (String MessCode, String MessText, Boolean Xit)
    {
        String Mess = "";                           // Start out with an empty Message to tell Joe User.
        String Title = "";                          // And an empty title too.



        MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog (Mess, Title);
        await messageDialog.ShowAsync ();           // Stop and wait for user to acknowledge.
        if (!Xit)                               // We're done here if we're not goin' down.
            return;

        //
        // If we're goin' down,
        // we have a lot of cleanup to do.
        //



        Application.Current.Exit ();                        // This should stop us. But it doesn't.
    }
```

Comment: I have read the guidelines. In this case, my app has an expiration date and the user is using it beyond its expiration. So you're suggesting I raise a Suspending event. I'll try that. Thank you.

Comment: What, no! In that case rather redirect your user to a "buy screen" and tell the user what is going on. Don't just kill the app; from the user's perspective what is the difference between the kill of the app and the app crashing? I't makes for very bad UX.

Comment: Thank you! That's a good idea. I'm going to re-think the whole "terminate the app" idea.

Answer (score 2):

#### How should I "properly" programmatically terminate a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

*The short: There isn't a "proper" way, and it's recommend that you shouldn't*

The remarks on the [Application.Exit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows.ui.xaml.application.exit) method states:

> Normally, however, you should not provide this UI because the system automatically manages app lifetime and terminates suspended apps as needed to free resources.

The [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465088.aspx) say you should:

> Design your app to suspend when the user switches away from it and resume when the user switches back to it.
>
> Don't terminate the app when the user navigates away from the app or closes the app using the close button. The operating system ensures that there is a consistent way for the user to access and manage apps. Your app is suspended when it is no longer visible to the user. By leaving the application lifecycle to the system, you ensure that your user can return to your app as efficiently as possible. Doing so also provides the best system performance and battery life from the device.

Rather register an event handler for the [Suspending](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br242341) event.

> It is called when the app is suspended. You can use this event handler to save relevant application and user data to persistent storage.

It is good to read the [Application Lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle) page.

#### How to programmatically terminate a Windows Phone 8.1 app?

*Windows Phone 8.1*

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```

*Windows Phone 8.1 (Silverlight)*

```
Application.Current.Terminate();
```

#### Your code

I used your code as is for testing, and it worked as expected when I remove:

```
if (!Xit)                               // We're done here if we're not goin' down.
        return;
```

`Xit` is never assigned in your code sample; if `Xit` is `false` then the termination line will not be reached. Just remember that `bool` values are `false` by default (if no value is given to them)

Comment: Xit is a boolean, the 3rd calling parameter to ShowAndGo. Please see the very first line of sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Application.Current.Terminate();` instead of `Application.Current.Exit ();`

For example

```
private void Exit_Button(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
  {
    Application.Current.Terminate();
  }
```

Comment: I tried. IntelliSense gives me the red squiggly under the word "Terminate" with the following error message: 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application' does not contain a definition for 'Terminate' and no extension method called 'Terminate' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Application' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly directive?)"